# Wait until flag = true fails, flag is always false

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a custom hook to save data on a server. Right now, I'm faking the server call with a simple `setTimeout` that sets the data created flag on `true` after 2 seconds.

I have a function that keeps checking the flag before it resolves a Promise.

However, the flag never becomes true. Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-bell-yw6cl).

I've seen other posts talking about that but I haven't been able to implement the solution.

**app.tsx**

```js
function App() {
  const { createOrganization } = useCreateOrganization();
  const handleCreateOrg = () => {
    createOrganization("New Org Name");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleCreateOrg}>Start process</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**useCreateOrganization.tsx**

```js
export const useCreateOrganization = (): {
  createOrganization: (organizationName: string) => Promise<any>;
} => {
  const [isOrganizationCreated, setIsOrganizationCreated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOrganizationCreated) {
      setIsOrganizationCreated(true);
    }
  }, [isOrganizationCreated]);

  // Fakes org creation on a server.
  const mockCreateOrg = (orgName: string) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsOrganizationCreated(true);
    }, 1500);
  };

  function until(conditionFunction): Promise<any> {
    const poll = (resolve, reject) => {
      if (conditionFunction()) {
        console.log("done");
        resolve();
      } else {
        console.log("not done yet!");
        setTimeout(_ => poll(resolve, reject), 500);
      }
    };

    return new Promise(poll);
  }

  const createOrganization = async (organizationName: string): Promise<any> => {
    mockCreateOrg(organizationName);
    setIsOrganizationCreated(false);
    return await until(() => isOrganizationCreated);
  };

  return { createOrganization };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isOrganizationCreated` will always hold the initial value `false`, because there is never a new value assigned to the variable in the function scope of `useCreateOrganization` - so it is more of a basic JavaScript closure thing (if you want to read more, look at *1 down under)

The problem also is, you want to implement imperative style polling (`until`) in React world. Instead you should embrace the declarative nature of React by using `state` and `props` to trigger a new render cycle. So instead of polling, you could call the `mockCreateOrg` API, which in turns sets the new state. This new state triggers a rerender, that could lead to side effects - e.g. `console.log("done")`.

I am not sure, why do you want to use Hooks in your sample exactly, so here is a basic fetch example with three states: When 1) the Hook is in `"idle"`, 2) the organization is being created (`"pending"`), 3) orga creation has completed (`"created"`).

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-sunset-b2r49)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useCreateOrganization = (): {
  createOrganization: (organizationName: string) => Promise<any>;
} => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<"idle" | "pending" | "created">("idle");

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (state === "pending") {
      interval = setInterval(() => console.log("not done yet!"), 500);
    } else if (state === "created") {
      console.log("done");
      // ...do some other things here...
      setState("idle");
    }
    return () => interval && clearInterval(interval);
  }, [state]);

  // Fakes org creation on a server.
  const mockCreateOrg = (orgName: string) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setState("created");
    }, 1500);
  };

  const createOrganization = async (organizationName: string): Promise<any> => {
    mockCreateOrg(organizationName);
    setState("pending");
  };

  return { createOrganization };
};

function App() {
  const { createOrganization } = useCreateOrganization();
  const handleCreateOrg = () => {
    createOrganization("New Org Name");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleCreateOrg}>Start process</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

---

#### Further info: closures in React Hooks (*1)

When you invoke the closure `createOrganization`, it will use the variable `isOrganizationCreated` defined in the outer scope (`useCreateOrganization` function body), which at invocation time has the initial state value `false`. `isOrganizationCreated` will always have the literal value `false` in this scope, a reassignment never happens (with `const` also not possible). By triggering a state change with `setIsOrganizationCreated`, React internally updates its [component memory cell](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components), and with a new render cycle invokes `useCreateOrganization` again - now with the updated `isOrganizationCreated` state. Though that doesn't change the closure scope of the first `useCreateOrganization` invocation.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: "Hope it helps"... are you kidding? It's perfect! Thank you so much. I've got a lot more than just getting my question answered, fair play to you.